# Mocking @ngrx/router-store's selectRouteParam

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-router-store

I have an Angular 8 app (core 8.1.2) using NgRx and the `@ngrx/router-store` (8.4.0) but am having trouble mocking a selector generated by `fromRouter.getSelectors(selectRouter)`.

The selector I have written and am trying to test looks like this:

```
export const selectFilteredPagedFeaturedPlaylists = createSelector(
  selectFilteredFeaturedPlaylists,
  selectRoutePageIndex,
  selectPageSize,
  (featuredPlaylists, pageIndex, pageSize) => ({
    ...featuredPlaylists,
    content: featuredPlaylists.content.slice(+pageIndex * pageSize, (+pageIndex + 1) * pageSize)
  })
);
```

and the `selectRoutePageIndex` selector, calling a method generated by the store, looks like this:

```
export const selectRoutePageIndex = selectRouteParam('pageIndex');
```

In reality, I am not necessarily concerned with mocking the `selectRouteParam` selector, but I need to mock my `selectRoutePageIndex` selector. Unfortunately, the [technique described in the docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#using-mock-selectors) doesn't appear to work for selectors generated by `@ngrx/router-store`.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to provide my solution in 2019. It's pretty similar to yours already. Here's how my selectors are setup for the router.

```
export const selectRouter = createSelector(
    (state: fromRoot.State) => state.router,
    value => value,
);

const {
    selectQueryParams, // select the current route query params
    selectQueryParam, // factory function to select a query param
    selectRouteParams, // select the current route params
    selectRouteParam, // factory function to select a route param
    selectRouteData, // select the current route data
    selectUrl, // select the current url
}: RouterStateSelectors<any> = fromRouter.getSelectors(selectRouter);
```

And then, in my test, I can mock out the router state like this.

```
mockStore.overrideSelector(fromCore.selectRouter, {
    state: {
        root: {
            params: {
                't': 'test', // query string parameter
            },
        },
    },
    navigationId: null,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I did not find an answer to my question, but I have created a workaround. I have wrapped the router store's selector in a `createSelector()` call and just returned it. It looks like this:

```js
export const innerSelectRoutePageIndex = selectRouteParam('pageIndex');

export const selectRoutePageIndex = createSelector(
  innerSelectRoutePageIndex,
  (routePageIndex) => routePageIndex
);
```

So the client code still uses the `selectRoutePageIndex` selector, and `MockStore.overrideSelector()` is happy with the arrangement. It seems that `createSelector()` is more forgiving of the signatures of the selectors it is passed.